# Замена невалидных html тэгов < и > на &lt; и &gt;

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

при отправке сообщения в телеграм с помощью бота, используется форматировка html, что значит при попытке запихать <аргумент> будет ошибка, и нужно заменять эти стрелочки на `&lt;` и `&gt;` но писать их каждый раз в куче текста просто адский не удобно, я хотел бы попробовать сделать регулярку которая будет заменять такие штуки автоматический но не трогать валидные html тэги к примеру:

Пример Валидного тэга который не нужно заменять

```
<a href="tg://user?id=1">Bot</a>
```

Невалидный тэг который требует замены

```
<аргумент команды>
```

Невалидный тэг который требует замены

```
< вам в ту сторону >.<
```

Код который я пытался реализовать но ничего не вышло(

```
import re

def replace_invalid_tags(html_string):
    invalid_tag_pattern = r'<[^a-zA-Z/!?](.*?)>'
    fixed_html = re.sub(invalid_tag_pattern, r'&lt;\1&gt;', html_string)
    return fixed_html

html_string = '<a href="#">Link</a> <argument1> <argument2>'
fixed_html = replace_invalid_tags(html_string)
print(fixed_html)
```

Comment: В случае текста`<a>`, вы хотели бы определять его как тег или как аргумент?

Comment: @diduk001 как аргумент, тэг только лишь если в конце есть закрывающая самого тэга </a> к примеру

Comment: а почему нельзя заменить все? вы пробовали? вроде это ен должно быть ошибкой

Comment: @VitaliyStop_RU_war_in_UA если заменить всё html тэги не будут подхватываться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте библиотеку [bleach](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). В ней есть возможность выбирать валидные тэги.

```
from bleach.sanitizer import Cleaner


html_test = '<h1><a href="#">Link</a> <argument1> <argument2><аргумент команды> < вам в ту сторону</h1>'

cleaner = Cleaner(tags=['h1', 'a'])
print(cleaner.clean(html_test))

------------------------------

 <h1><a href="#">Link</a> &lt;argument1&gt; &lt;argument2&gt;&lt;аргумент команды&gt; &lt; вам в ту сторону</h1>
```

Comment: если в тексте будет такая ссылка <a href="tg://user?id=2135121152">Link</a> он срезает полностью href и оставляет лишь пустой <a>Link</a> как это поправить?

Comment: @Lumo Лучше, конечно, создать новый вопрос, чтоб если кому другому понадобиться, то он бы быстро нашел. А так, надо добавить "tg" в протоколы `cleaner = Cleaner(tags=['h1', 'a'], protocols=frozenset({'http', 'https', 'mailto', 'tg'}))`

Comment: я ещё увидел что библиотека уже не актульна тк как заброшена, увидел в её ишьюсах аналог под названием nh3, подскажите вы знакомы с ним?

Comment: @Lumo Нет, да и с этой я познакомился только когда отвечал на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Понял спасибо вам!